# How to use radioButton to performe different equations with user input?

Tags: java, android, validation, radio-button

I'm having trouble using radioButtons to perform different calculations with the user input. If radioButton.isChecked, the user inserts its values and the 'calculate' button is clicked, and I can't retrieve the answers.

I've tried if/else statements inside the OnClickListener but the app crash if I select the respective button.

Let me explain my code:

1. The user selects the desired radioButton;
2. The user inserts its data and it's validated: the field can't be empty or have only a dot (.) (as a form of not letting the app crash, and it's working perfectly);
3. The user clicks on "Calculate" button and then retrieve on a TextView its answers with respect of the selected radioButton.

Here it is:

```
calcbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
   if (view.getId() == R.id.calcbtn){
     float n1, n2;
     String value1 = vol.getText().toString();     //storing user inputs
     String value2 = tempo.getText().toString();
     if (value1.equals("") || value1.equals(".")) { //validation starts in this line
         n1 = 0;
     } else {
         n1 = Float.parseFloat(value1);
     }
     if (value2.equals("") || value2.equals(".")) {
         n2 = 0;
     } else {
         n2 = Float.parseFloat(value2);
     }                                               //validation ends
     if (radioButton1.isChecked()){                  //calculation starts
         float ansA = n1/(n2*3);
             resultATextView.setText(String.format("The result A is: ", ansA));
         float ansB = n1/n2;
             resultBTextView.setText(String.format("The result B is: ", ansB));
       }
       else if (radioButton2.isChecked()){
         float ansC = (n1/n2)*20;
            resultCTextView.setText(String.format("The result C is: ", ansC));
         float ansD = (n1/n2)*60;
            resultDTextView.setText(String.format("The result D is: ", ansD));
       }
   }
}
});
```

I should be retrieving the answers in each respected TextView but the app crashes if I just select a button.
I'm Java beginner and thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Could you please specify expected results and the results that you're currently getting?

Comment: Yes. Let's take the radioButton1 checked: If the user inputs value1 = n1 =  500.0; and value 2 = n2 = 5. The output, when the user clicks "calculate", in answer A should be (n1/n2*3) = 500/(5*3) = 33.3 and answer B, 100.0.

Comment: Check the answer. The code works right. You just need to provide output by adding argument into `String.format()`. So you just need to add the `%f` as it is shown below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the problem occurs because of the output. There are no formatters.

`String.format("The result D is: ", ansD);`

To make it provide the correct output try:

```
String.format("The result A is: %.1f", ansA);
String.format("The result B is: %.1f", ansB);
String.format("The result C is: %.1f", ansC);
String.format("The result D is: %.1f", ansD);
```

[image]

Comment: That's that! Solved! I was not paying attention on this detail. And another thing was resposible for crashing: I've marked onClick on each button on .xml file and was not having a correpondent on .java so each time I was clicking on the button, it was crashing the app. Thank you very, very much! Working perfectly!

Comment: My pleasure, have a happy coding!